# PHP templates updating all html document

Tags: php, html

I have a lot of webpages that all have the same title and the client keeps asking me to change the name of the title, is it possible to use php to update all the titles in the html document at once?

Thanks

edit: I don't have any knowledge of PHP beyond using wordpress, I was thinking it would probably look similar to the get_header link, but when searching PHP get I don't get anything I can make use of.

Comment: The simple answer to this is yes, it is quite simple.  However it is difficult to help unless you provide at least some sample code.  And by this, I mean not the HTML alone, but what php code have you tried?

Comment: Hint:  use an include file

Comment: Thanks I will search include file :)

Comment: Here's a starter:   `<?php $title='titlename'; ?>`  named something like title.php. and then in your main documents, simply `include_once('title.php');`    Then in your html just do something like this inside the head, `<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>`

Comment: I'm a little new to stack overflow, not sure how I can give you a green tick?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I entered the answer below to make it easier.  If it solved your problem, just click the check mark on the left (if that's what you mean by a green tick) to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create a separate file named something like title.php

The only thing you need in this file is something like this:

```
<?php 

$title='titlename'; 

?>
```

Then in all of the php files that need this (note, if you've been saving them as .html they may not work;  most of the time they will  need to be .php)  add this at the top of your page

```
<?php
include_once('title.php');
?>
```

Below, all you need to do is inside the head tag is this

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

Any time you need to change the title name, just change it in the title.php file.